# Confused about execution order

Tags: reactjs

In my react app, I have an `app.jsx` component in which I perform basic functions such as getting window size, read user info by calling an API function, etc.

This is really the top level component at the entry point. This is what my entry point looks like:

```
render (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App>
            <HomePageComponent />
        </App>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

What I'm confused about is that in the home page component, I have a bunch of sub components. Looks like the `componentDidMount()` function of a sub component inside the home page is executing **before** the `componentDidMount()` function of the `App` component.

Is this the way it is supposed to work? From the inside out? I was putting some basic house keeping functions like getting user info inside the `App` component thinking it would execute first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour. There's a discussion about it in [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2763) issue.

Some highlights:

> If componentDidMount executed parent-first, the only thing you'd find there is your node, because all child nodes have not been mounted by this moment. This makes componentDidMount useless for majority of use cases (e.g. counting offsetWidth, attaching third-party non-React plugins, etc). **(gaearon)**
>
> It's not a bug but maybe confusing docs. It's the creation order of the DOM elements. It has nothing to do with being in the document or not, since we cannot guarantee that anyway (since the root may be out of the document). **(sebmarkbage)**
>
> Technically the life-cycle methods only guarantee that your particular component is mounted. It doesn't make any promises with regard to it's children. Relying on this order is usually indication that you're breaking the encapsulation boundaries of components. **(sebmarkbage)**

Comment: Thank you! With that said, where's the best place to handle these house-keeping items then? Or is it better to call a general function from all parent and sub components so that whoever gets there first will execute this general function. I can then use some logic to make sure that I don't make the API call again and again but the data is stored locally in my redux store or localstorage.

Comment: @Sam You could grab the window size at any point, even outside the render method. And you could have your `App` component conditionally render its children based on whether the API call has returned or not. There isn't one correct answer to this "house-keeping" question though. It will depend on a lot of variables regarding how your app is architected.

Comment: @Sam There are different ways of doing this but what I tend to do is firing off my requests when the app loads and then mount while I wait for the response. Then I update my redux store and data trickles down. This means all my components have to be able to handle that they might be missing some properties and render a spinner or nothing if they lack any props.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the way it's supposed to work. This isn't a React issue so much as a JSX one. JSX just transforms into function calls. For example, your code turns into:

```
React.createElement(
    Provider,
    { store: store },
    React.createElement(
        App,
        null,
        React.createElement(HomePageComponent, null)
    )
);
```

It's just like the following:

```
doSomethingSecond(doSomethingFirst());
```

In that example, `doSomethingFirst` will execute first, and the result will be passed as an argument to `doSomethingSecond`. Similarly, in the JSX-transformed code, `React.createElement(HomePageComponent, null)` will execute first, and the result will be passed as an argument to the wrapping `React.createelement` call, and so on.

You can get a better sense of how JSX is turned into JS on [Babel's site](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=DwBQTg9gbglgJgUzAAgM4BcJgQXgN4ZYIC-AfAFDJXLACCADvRdSzQBIQC2CIAhgOYIAwl3oQAdgnHpkAembVgshk3JLw0eElJA).

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. Could you please see my comment under the other answer? Trying to figure out the best approach in handling these house keeping items.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> constructor() method to load initial operations for your cookings.
>    later provide your componentDidMount() operations and so on..

For better understanding see
[React Component Life Cycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)